# using yaml in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

I've written a restful web service that the Post produces a Kafka message and the Get consumes from Kafka Topic. I hard coded the properties that allowed me to connect to Kafka. I want to move that to a yaml file in src/main/resources

```
producer:
  bootstrap.servers: "localhost:9092"
  acks: "all"
  retries: 0
  batch.size: 16384
  linger.ms: 1
  buffer.memory: 33554432
  key.serializer: "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer"
  value.serializer: "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer"
```

I then attempt to get this in my Kafka Producer Code

```
@Service
public class SonicRestKafkaProducer {
    @Value("${producer.bootstrap.servers}")
    String bootStrapServers;

public void buildProducer() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        if (bootStrapServers == null) {System.out.println("bootStrapServers is null");}
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", bootStrapServers);
```

Which results in a null pointer.

```
bootStrapServers is null
2016-02-15 17:09:14.941 ERROR 10846 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:459) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at com.sonicdrivein.bdp.kafka.restproxy.kafka.api.SonicRestKafkaProducer.buildProducer(SonicRestKafkaProducer.java:59) ~[kafka-rest-proxy-0.1.0.jar!/:0.1.0]
```

I've tried creating a separate class. I feel like it's something simple but I'm not seeing anything in the docs or here that explains it.

Comment: **1)** Please share  the code loading your `yaml` file as well. **2)** Who is calling your `buildProducer()` method and where... please be aware that autowiring/injection happens after object instantiations (for obvious reasons), thus usage in constructors may be problematic...

Comment: Rather than using `@Value`, I'd recommend using [`@ConfigurationProperties`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties)

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I did try `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="producer")
public class SonicRestKafkaProducer {
 @Value("${bootstrap.servers}")
 String bootStrapServers;` and I still get the null pointer

Comment: @Morfic I'm not writing code to load the yaml. I'm assuming that spring boot loads it for me. I could be wrong. The class is currently written as a singleton. I want to move away from that. The buildProducer creates a kafka producer. If there is an error then I close the kafka producer and null out the class variable. Anytime this variable is used to talk to kafka, I check to see if it is null and I call buildProducer to create a new one. One producer is recommended by kafka.

Comment: @Morfic as a singleton my constructor is private. I've wondered if this is an issue.

Comment: Well, according to the [Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-yaml) and @AndyWilkinson 's suggestion, there's a little work you have to do with `ConfigurationProperties`.